# Google Maps V3 not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to update our journey planner to use Google Maps V3. I didn't write the original code and am struggling to get it to work. I'm hoping someone can help.

The working old v2 page can be seen here

http://www.connectteesvalley.com/jplanner1.asp

I'm trying to implement v3 on a test page here

http://www.connectteesvalley.com/jplanner1testing.asp

The map displays, which is great. And I have checked numerous times for any functions which aren't now usable in v3, but when I click the "begin my journey"-button it doesn't advance, are there any debuggers out there that could help me pinpoint the erroneous code? As it stands I'm not sure where it is actually failing.

IE Debugger is throwing up an error here

```
function removeMarker(markerID){
    var len = markersArr.length;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        if (markerID.toLowerCase() == markersArr[i].id.toLowerCase()){
            markersArr[i].remove();
        }
    }
}
```

saying Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'

however i've looked around here and its used quite often.

Thanks

Comment: changed 
    markersArr[i].remove();

to

markersArr[i].setMap(null);

it seems to of passed this error but is now struggling on 

marker.setImage(imageUrl);

can anyone confirm the above change is correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out by yourself, you need to use setMap(null). Regarding your problem with marker.setImage(imageUrl), you need to use [marker.setIcon()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) instead.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, your time is much appreciated. 

I've changed setImage to SetIcon and now IE debugger isn't showing any errors yet my page still wont progress when i hit the, 'begin Journey' button.

Im not sure what my next step should be.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your JavaScript and start stepping through your code.